# Large number of seed questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've noticed a large number of "seed" questions on the site.  The questions don't have much content to work with themselves, just a question in the title.

The topics seem ok, but the questions themselves don't encourage answers.  What can we do to make these questions better?

Comment: Related:  http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/92/texas-holdem-shotgun-questions

Answer (score 4):

People should be encouraged to improve their questions.  Leave comments asking for clarification and vote down questions that are very vague and lack merit.  I'm very sparing on when I actually vote things down, and prefer to encourage people to post better answers.  If they're an established user, I'm much more likely to vot ethem down.

If the questions are obvious spam, flag them and vote to close them.

Comment: I think this is a different issue. There we talking about the flood, rep gathering questions and here we talk about legitimate good intention but bad written question. And this should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Those questions were part of what I thought of, but I really think there are some other questions that fit.  On topic, but just poor quality.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: +1 I've voted down / voted to close poorly phrased questions. However I've resisted doing the same for string of questions from the same user, it's early days ...

Answer (score 1):

Good observation.

We need change this before go public. We can review our questions and post a suggestion to OP improve the question where we find a poor on-topic question.